# Fail to runserver when adding django-import-export package into Django project

Tags: python, django, django-import-export

I am currently working with a project that requires import an excel file into Django database. I googled it and found out that django-import-export package is exactly what I want.

However, when I import "import_export" into my "settings.py" or "from import_export.admin import ImportExportModelAdmin" into my "admin.py", the error appears although I have successfully installed this package. I have also followed the tutorial [here](https://django-import-export.readthedocs.io/en/latest/), but the result is still the same.

Is there any way to solve this problem or any suggestions? Could you please help me? Thanks in advance!

Here is the code from a tutorial on youtube that I used for testing:

```
/*admin.py*/
from django.contrib import admin
# Register your models here.
from .models import *
from import_export.admin import ImportExportModelAdmin

@admin.register(Laptop, Desktop, Mobile)
class ViewAdmin(ImportExportModelAdmin):
  pass
```

---

```
/*settings.py*/
INSTALLED_APPS = [
  ...
  'import_export',
]
```

---

```
/*After running python manage.py runserver */
Watching for file changes with StatReloader
Performing system checks...

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 24, in <module>
    main()
  File "manage.py", line 20, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\FWTools\WinPython-201702\python-3.6.2\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 401, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\FWTools\WinPython-201702\python-3.6.2\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 395, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "C:\FWTools\WinPython-201702\python-3.6.2\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 328, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "C:\FWTools\WinPython-201702\python-3.6.2\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 60, in execute
    super().execute(*args, **options)
  File "C:\FWTools\WinPython-201702\python-3.6.2\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 369, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "C:\FWTools\WinPython-201702\python-3.6.2\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 95, in handle
    self.run(**options)
  File "C:\FWTools\WinPython-201702\python-3.6.2\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 102, in run
    autoreload.run_with_reloader(self.inner_run, **options)
  File "C:\FWTools\WinPython-201702\python-3.6.2\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 599, in run_with_reloader
    start_django(reloader, main_func, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\FWTools\WinPython-201702\python-3.6.2\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 584, in start_django
    reloader.run(django_main_thread)
  File "C:\FWTools\WinPython-201702\python-3.6.2\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 299, in run
    self.run_loop()
  File "C:\FWTools\WinPython-201702\python-3.6.2\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 305, in run_loop
    next(ticker)
  File "C:\FWTools\WinPython-201702\python-3.6.2\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 345, in tick
    for filepath, mtime in self.snapshot_files():
  File "C:\FWTools\WinPython-201702\python-3.6.2\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 361, in snapshot_files
    for file in self.watched_files():
  File "C:\FWTools\WinPython-201702\python-3.6.2\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 260, in watched_files
    yield from iter_all_python_module_files()
  File "C:\FWTools\WinPython-201702\python-3.6.2\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 105, in iter_all_python_module_files
    return iter_modules_and_files(modules, frozenset(_error_files))
  File "C:\FWTools\WinPython-201702\python-3.6.2\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 118, in iter_modules_and_files
    if module.__name__ == '__main__':
  File "C:\FWTools\WinPython-201702\python-3.6.2\lib\site-packages\py\_apipkg.py", line 171, in __getattribute__
    return getattr(getmod(), name)
  File "C:\FWTools\WinPython-201702\python-3.6.2\lib\site-packages\py\_error.py", line 44, in __getattr__
    raise AttributeError(name)
AttributeError: __name__
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you get the [example application](https://django-import-export.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html#example-app) working first.

1. Clone repo from [github](https://github.com/django-import-export/django-import-export)
2. Install dependencies into a virtual env (e.g. `pip install -r requirements/test.txt`)
3. Follow [these instructions](https://django-import-export.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html#example-app) to install and load the example app.

Once you have the example application running, you have the basis for developing your own.